# Android eclipse resource strings error

Tags: android, eclipse

When I make a new android project and I go to res/values/string.xml I get a screen to add android resources instead of a XML document. I keeps getting the error about : `java.lang.NullPointerException.`

Is there a way to just alter a XML file (like suggested in tutorials)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small tab bar on the bottom in eclipse, where you can switch between the GUI and the plain XML file (only visible if you have already opened the file)

Answer (score 0):

do you create a new xml with java or the Android xml file ? because with java it's not gonna work .